# Referencing C functions in static library from C++

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I have a static library of functions written in C.  Let's say the header file is called myHeader.h and looks like:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

void function1();
void function2();

#endif
```

function1 and function2 aren't anything too special.  Let's say they exist in a file called impl1.c which looks like:

```
#include "myHeader.h"

void function1() {
    // code
}
void function2() {
    // more code
}
```

All of the code mentioned so far is compiled into some static library called libMyLib.a.  I'd rather not modify any of the code used to build this library.  I also have a C++ header (cppHeader.h) that looks like:

```
#ifndef CPPHEADER_H
#define CPPHEADER_H

class CppClass {
    private:
        double attr1;
    public:
        void function3();
};
#endif
```

Then cppHeader.cpp looks like:

```
#include "cppHeader.h"
#include "myHeader.h"

// constructor
CppClass::CppClass(){}

void CppClass::function3() {
    function1();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error about an undefined reference to function1().  I believe that I've linked everything properly when compiling.  I'm pretty rusty in my C++.  I'm sure that I'm just doing something stupid.  I hope that my simple example code illustrates the problem well enough.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can't say anything about `C++`, but in `C` you might want to make your function declarations proper prototypes ... just specify `void` for the parameters: `void function1(void);`

Comment: @pmg - I thought that hadn't been "required" since 1989!

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: @awoodland: In the current C99 `void function1();` is a declaration; `void function2(void);` is a prototype. Depending on how it's implemented you can call function1 as `function1();` or `function1(foobar)` or ...; function2 **must** be called as `function2()` and implemented accordingly.

Comment: @pmg - Interesting. Shows how much C I use!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other solution (to the one suggested originally by Yann) is to surround your "C" header with:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
```

Which saves you from having to remember to do:

```
 extern "C" {
 #include "foo.h"
 }
```

every place you use `foo.h`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to use:

```
extern "C" {
 #include "myHeader.h"
}
```

Or else the C++ compiler will generate symbol names which are name-mangled.