# Linking flags order using QMAKE in QTCreator .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking, qmake

I'm getting

> [...]main.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to [...]

I already know the cause, but, I can't resolve it using `QMAKE_` flags.

I need to set the `-I` flag in linking after the `-L` and before the `-o` flag, like this (I tested a handmade Makefile, and it's OK):

> -L ./lib -lm [... other libs ...] -I ./include -o ./bin/program

But setting `-I` in `QMAKE_LFLAGS`, the `-I` flag goes in the beginning of `g++` command.

Comment: Compiler flags (including preprocessor flags like `-I`) traditionally goes first. Link libraries in many cases *must* be last (or at least behind any source/object files).

Comment: There is some way to force -I flag to go after -L and before -o in linking?

Comment: Probably not, but why would you want it? Except for linker libraries the order really doesn't matter. It will be easier to tell what's wrong if you show the *complete* and *unedited* error message. Most likely you are missing an object file or a library, because the part of the error message you show is a *linker* error, so the C++ compiler or preprocessor flags are irrelevant anyway.

Comment: I created a test "environment". I compiled a simple math library in C standard, to compute max and min functions:
* .c file: http://pastebin.com/mZqLyS2C
* .h file: http://pastebin.com/NwnXRnF6

The makefile to compile my library: http://pastebin.com/117u7K8N

Now, I have the `.a` and the `.h` files, and I want to link it in a C++ project, inside `QT`. My `QT` project is a simple Hello World function that calls min or max function I'v declared in my static library. And I simply can't link it.. the error is:

Comment: And what does your `.pro` file look like? Or at least the linker-specific lines?

Comment: .pro file: http://pastebin.com/6YQYx7TF

Answer (score -1):

Similar solution:
[Referencing C functions in static library from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292307/referencing-c-functions-in-static-library-from-c)

To instance a C lib from C++, you need to surround c headers with `extern "C" { }`